# Как сделать, чтобы некая строка была записана в текстовой файл?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы некая строка была записана в текстовой файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Яваскрипт(Иешный ActiveX не в счет) не имеет доступа к записи файлов. Единственный выход - Аякс. Посылаете запрос в файл PHP, который формирует файл и отсылает обратно клиенту

Comment: Спасибо, но я профан, могли бы подробно скинуть пример. Новичок в этой области!

Comment: Напишите подробнее, что хотите! Хотя бы где находится файл?? На клиенте ли, на сервере? Зачем это нужно (м.б. посоветуем лучшие способы)?

Comment: Все достаточно элементарно, вообще идея такова, сделать автозаполнение поля, откуда он будет брать записи из файла. Но для начала хочу понять сами понятия файла, как создавать, как читать, как в массив их записывать. Файл будет находиться на локальном компьютере, в дальнейшем - на сервере, откуда будет читаться вся информация!